# Keep losing WiFi connection: Realtek RTL8188CE

Tags: wireless, networking, realtek

My wifi connection keeps dropping. Wireless card is a Realtek RTL8188CE, on a Thinkpad T430. It seems to be something to do with the ARP table: whenever it drops I see unanswered ARP requests from my computer asking what MAC 192.168.2.1 (my router) has.

Turning on and off wifi seems to fix it for about a minute, but then the problem comes back.

This is quite a big problem. I'm unable to use the wifi for longer than about a minute.

Comment: Possibly the same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/296833/realtek-rtl8188ce-network-adapter-repeatedly-drops-connection/338482#338482 I just answered...

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling IPv6 in network connections for your wifi. Hope this helps. Saw the same answer from other forums so don't have an explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is for the driver uses the system in Ubuntu, if you use the realtek win xp drivers with the ndiswrapper (driver winxp64 versión in the 64 Ubuntu versión) the card go so fine

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are recommending here. Could you please elaborate on your answer by including the installation/configuration steps required? Thanks.

Comment: And don't forget to separate the text from the code in your answer. I can't tell if the first word over there is "is" or if it's the terminal command `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same hardware as i do and had the same problem i had many months ago. So i hope this works for you.
Open a terminal and type the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git 
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

If you find the wifi isn't as stable as you'd expect, use this command after booting (yes everytime sorry).

```
sudo modprobe rtl8188CE
```

Make sure your software, os and kernel are up to date too.

Good luck and happy coding!