# Realtek RTL8188CE network adapter repeatedly drops connection

Tags: wireless, networking, realtek

Variations of this problem certainly seem to be common, but I'm not not seeing a recent solution for my case: I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, 
`uname -r` = 3.8.0-21-generic
`lspci` = 02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)

The wifi network connection is relatively slow, but more seriously, repeatedly drops completely every few minutes. It usually recovers in a minute or so, but then drops again in 1-3 minutes. Running Windows 8 (ugh) on the same system, the connection never drops. Some of the solutions proposed, involve compiling/installing a new driver from Realtek - I'm really not comfortable doing that. Another suggested adding a `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192.conf` file containing a "`options rtl8192ce ips=0 debug=2`" line. I tried that - no effect. Another solution proposed deleting the network manager and installing something called "`wicd`". I haven't tried that yet, wondering, if "`wicd`" didn't help/work, could I use apt-get to purge it and re-install the network manager to get back to where I am?

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you set the ipv6 to "ignore"?  A friend found wicd reconnected much faster than networkmanager, so was more usable, but still had disconnects.

Comment: For reasons unknown, the disconnects are much less frequent today even before disabling Ipv6. I disabled Ipv6 using the instructions in [link](http://ithelpblog.com/os/linux/debian/ubuntu-debian/howto-disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04-11-10-11-04/) and the speed is still quite slow - about half what I see with an older notebook running Ubuntu 12.04, even though my router and new notebook are 802.11 n enabled and the old notebook is not.

Comment: Check for errors and signal strengths with ifconfig, iwconfig, and sudo iwlist scan.  W8 may handle errors differently, e.g. maybe just ignoring them rather than trying to reconnect for a better connection.

Comment: I believe I managed to disable 802.11n and my connection speeds are now comparable to what I see with my old laptop running Ubuntu 12.04. The connection drops continue. I compared the quality and error data from ifconfig, iwconfig, iwlist scan to what I see on the old laptop, they're similar and seem "OK". I guess I can live with this (and hope that a future Ubuntu update fixes the problem). I'd hoped that a new laptop and new router that supported "n" would yield better performance.

Answer (score 3):

You mention that you aren't comfortable compiling and installing a driver, but unfortunately you can't do this without that.  Fortunately, because of the pain I went through personally, I have made it as easy as possible for you.  I fixed the compile issues on 13.04 with the RTL8188CE driver and put [detailed instructions](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/blob/master/README.md) for install up on my [Git Hub](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver).

This version fixes the compile error and also fixes the hard-coded Tx Power value that  was set to 22 dBm.

First install Git and build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install git
apt-get install gcc build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Then clone the repo.  I like to make a directory in my home folder and put it there:

```
cd ~
mkdir gitclone && cd gitclone
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/blob/master/README.md
cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver
```

Then follow the instructions in `README.md`

EDIT: 22-Jan-2015

It is now even easier.  Install git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

and run this command

```
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver.git && cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver && ./install.sh`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this blog post](http://www.perseosblog.com/en/posts/solving-connection-problem-with-realtek-wifi-card-rtl8188ce-rtl8192ce-rtl8191se-and-rtl8192de-on-debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives/) and my own attempts to solve the problem (though I haven't run it for long, so YMMV), you can try the following:

Firstly, [download the manufacturer drivers](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/). You'll need to navigate through the tree to find the right one (in an attempt to keep this post somewhat future proof). Certainly, for me to get the RTL8188CE driver, I navigated to the `IEEE 802.11b/g/n single-chip` option, and then just ticked the relevant boxes.

Next untar the sources and attempt to install with `sudo make`, `sudo make install`. The sources I downloaded required some modification. It seems that the `__devinit` macros were [removed from the kernel in 3.8](http://lwn.net/Articles/537562/), so I had to remove `__devinit` from `pci.h` and `pci.c` and also remove `__devinitdata` from each `sw.c` in each of the driver directories (that is, I removed the single word in the function definition). After that, `make` and `make install` worked just fine.

I think that should be sufficient as it seems to overwrite the previously installed `rtl8192ce.ko` module, so it should just work with the new driver on reboot.

I expect it would be necessary to redo this after each kernel upgrade (assuming you still need it of course!).